# NGINX: Is possible to get how many times an user hit my vhost?

Tags: nginx

I am using the nginx limitreq directive nowadays and I want to replace it by Google recaptcha instead of blocking the user right away...

I can do this in my app but I was trying to make nginx help in it instead of coding this in the app...

Basically I would like to send to the upstream in a new header how many times that IP hit my nginx vhost and let the application insert the recaptcha if this header is greater than a value... Do you think this is possible in nginx without any custom module?

[]s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any other custom modules, it's not possible. 
Because limit_req module (which is included by default) only supports http return (like 504,502,etc..). [nginx limit_req document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html)